# Delete consecutive sequences of rows for entire site ID's

Tags: r

I've got a dataframe that looks like this:

```
year  percent  site
2011  15       tex21
2012  76       tex21
2011  12       ca34
2012  13       ca34
2011  32       tex21
2012  45       tex21 
2013  32       tex21
```

I want to delete keep the first consecutive run of each site based on row order, and delete the second run. So in the example above, I want to delete the second `tex21`. I can do:

```
df %>% distinct(year, site)
```

But this doesn't remove the entire second duplicated site. Instead it does this:

```
year  percent  site
2011  15       tex21
2012  76       tex21
2011  12       ca34
2012  13       ca34
2013  32       tex21
```

And what I want to do is this:

```
year  percent  site
2011  15       tex21
2012  76       tex21
2011  12       ca34
2012  13       ca34
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I don't understand. In your `df %>% distinct(year, site)` output you have 3 `tex21`s, all with different years: 2011, 2012, and 2013. Why do you want to delete the 2013 `tex21`, but not the 2012?

Comment: Because the first 2012 (with percent = 76) belongs to the timeseries of the first `tex21` and I want to preserve that timeseries. I want to delete the whole second `tex21` because it is a different timeseries but with duplicated name to the first `tex21`.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question. You say *"I want to delete the sites where that have the same year and site"*, but it seems like year has nothing to do with it - you want to keep the first consecutive run of each `site` based on row order.

Comment: So if I kept the 2013 value it would get added to the first `tex21` but that would be wrong, These are in fact two different time-series.

Comment: Ok, yes, thank you. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution using the `data.table::rleid` function which is often helpful when you care about consecutive runs of things.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(grouper = data.table::rleid(site)) %>%
  group_by(site) %>%
  filter(grouper == min(grouper)) %>%
  select(-grouper)
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   site [2]
#    year percent site 
#   <int>   <int> <chr>
# 1  2011      15 tex21
# 2  2012      76 tex21
# 3  2011      12 ca34 
# 4  2012      13 ca34
```

Using this data:

```
data = read.table(text = 'year  percent  site
2011  15       tex21
2012  76       tex21
2011  12       ca34
2012  13       ca34
2011  32       tex21
2012  45       tex21 
2013  32       tex21',  header = TRUE)
```